# How to parse TwitchTV Api?

Tags: php, parsing

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams');
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($json);

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($jsonDecoded));
fclose($fp);
```

I need only 2 field from `https://api.twitch.tv`.

It's streams->channel->name and streams->viewers;

How can I create good for each construction?

Comment: You need to ask a specific question in order for someone to give you an answer. Also what isn't working?

Comment: I got big massive. I need short massive with 2 fields, channel name and stream viewers. I need help with php.foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate over it and copy like that:

```
$streams = array();
foreach ($jsonDecoded->streams as $stream) {
    $streams[$stream->channel->display_name] = $stream->viewers;
}
```

Then you can operate with it like with others key=>value php array, i.e.:

```
foreach ($streams as $stream => $viewers) {
    echo $stream.": ".$viewers."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($jsonDecoded->streams as $stream) {
    $streams[$stream->channel->display_name] = $stream->viewers;
}
```

This didn't work for me. I had to change it to this for it to work:

```
foreach ($jsonDecoded->streams as $stream) {
    $streams[$stream->channel->display_name] = $stream->viewers;
}
```